# MySQL ODBC shows Decimals as Empty in Excel VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, odbc, decimal

I was just trying to make a toy database with MySQL and import it to Excel via VBA.
It was fine when I used MySQL's Excel plugin, but when I tried to automate it via VBA, it imported all the columns correctly except the Decimal(65,30) ones, which is shown as "empty" values in myArray.
Codes:

```vb
Sub DBUpdate()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells.ClearContents
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Database_Name As String

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")        'EBGen-Daily'
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
        Server_Name = .Range("IPaddress").Value
        Database_Name = .Range("DBname").Value      'Name of database'
        User_ID = .Range("userID").Value            'id user or username'
        Password = .Range("password").Value         'Password'

        SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM trade_details"
    End With

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")       'NEW STATEMENT
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
            Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    Dim myArray()

    myArray = rs.GetRows()

    nCols = UBound(myArray, 1)
    nRows = UBound(myArray, 2)

    For K = 0 To nCols ' Using For loop data are displayed
        ' header
        Range("b1").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name
        ' row data
        For R = 0 To nRows
           'Range("b2").Offset(R, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
           ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells(R, K).Value = myArray(K, R)
        Next
    Next

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

One thing I noticed is that the real null values are shown as *'NULL'* but the numbers are shown as *'Empty'*, and the type is *'Variant/Empty'*.

I also read that Excel is only scanning the first 8 rows by default to determine column type. But I have data populated starting the first row (and even if it is the case, it cannot be 'empty' right?)

System specs:

- Win10 64bit
- Office 2013
- 64bit MySQL
- Server 5.7
- MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver

I am really confused since everything is stock configuration and I do even know whether this is from the Excel/VBA side or MySQL/ODBC side, and not even a single person encountered this problem when i googled.
Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Why use arrays? Consider [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx)?

Comment: Also, that column type is incredibly large -the [max of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html): max digits of 65 and max 30 decimal point places. Try defining array with [double type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx) to accommodate. Integers or long types are too limited.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error and resolved by adjusting decimal down to say (10,7). Is there a reason you need such high integer value and decimal precision at MySQL's maximum?

Comment: Many thanks Parfait! I guess i am going with that solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, Excel's cell limit or interface does not accommodate the maximum decimal limit of MySQL (65,30). In VBA, using the *Double* type may maintain the numeric value. But for work on the spreadsheet, consider reducing the decimal field in MySQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `tableName` MODIFY COLUMN `largenumberfield` DECIMAL(10,7);
```

Additionally, consider bypassing the need of the VBA array and use the recordset as the only container of data. In Excel, you can use the range property, `CopyFromRecordset` where you specify the leftmost column of the data. You can also use the recordset's `Field.Name` property to pull in column headers:

```vb
Sub DBUpdate()
    Dim Server_Name As String, SQLStr As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String, Password As String

    Dim Cn As Object, rs As Object, fld As Object
    Dim i as Integer

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")        'EBGen-Daily'
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
        Server_Name = .Range("IPaddress").Value
        Database_Name = .Range("DBname").Value      'Name of database'
        User_ID = .Range("userID").Value            'id user or username'
        Password = .Range("password").Value         'Password'

        SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM trade_details"
    End With

    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")       
    Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
            Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
            ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    ' OPEN RECORDSET
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Cells.ClearContents

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    i = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' DATA ROWS
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```